# Converting byte arrays (from readfile) to string

Tags: c#, type-conversion

So, I am using `ReadFile` from `kernel32` for reading the file. Here is my code in reading files with the help of `SetFilePointer` and `ReadFile`.

```
public long ReadFileMe(IntPtr filehandle, int startpos, int length, byte[] outdata)
{
    IntPtr filea = IntPtr.Zero;
    long ntruelen = GetFileSize(filehandle, filea);
    int nRequestStart;
    uint nRequestLen;
    uint nApproxLength;
    int a = 0;
    if (ntruelen <= -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (ntruelen == 0)
    {
        return -2;
    }

    if (startpos > ntruelen)
    {
        return -3;
    }
    else if (length <= 0)
    {
        return -5;
    }
    else if (length > ntruelen)
    {
        return -6;
    }
    else
    {
        nRequestStart = startpos;
        nRequestLen = (uint)length;

        outdata = new byte[nRequestLen - 1];

        SetFilePointer(filehandle, (nRequestStart - 1), ref a, 0);
        ReadFile(filehandle, outdata, nRequestLen, out nApproxLength, IntPtr.Zero);
        return nApproxLength; //just for telling how many bytes are read in this function
    }
}
```

When I used this function, it works (for another purpose) so this code is tested and works.

But the main problem is, I now need to convert the `outdata` on the parameter which the function puts the bytes into `string`.

I tried using `Encoding.Unicode` and so on (all UTF), but it doesn't work.

Comment: did you try this: string result = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(outdata); and see whether you are able to get the output converted to string.

Comment: I had tried that too. It doesn't give any result..

Comment: Without a return parameter or a reference parameter, the function will put nothing in it...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`Encoding.GetString (Byte[], Int32, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getstring.aspx) method. this decodes a sequence of `byte`s from the specified `byte` array into a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... Encoding.Name_of_encoding.GetString must work...
try smth like this:

```
var convertedBuffer = Encoding.Convert(
             Encoding.GetEncoding( /*name of encoding*/),Encoding.UTF8, outdata);
var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(convertedBuffer);
```

**UPDATE**:
and what about this?:

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\test.txt", true))
        {
            var currentEncoding = streamReader.CurrentEncoding.EncodingName;
            Console.WriteLine(currentEncoding);
        }
```

Comment: yeah. but the name of encoding is what i'm looking for >.<

Comment: it says that it is on unicode (UTF-8). But I did tried unicode and utf-8

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add the out parameter on `outdata` parameter :
[Passing Arrays Using ref and out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szasx730%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
public long ReadFileMe(IntPtr filehandle, int startpos, int length, out byte[] outdata)
```